# Powers of 10 in cutoff frequency formula for capacitor

Tags: capacitance, cutoff-frequency

I need to know which values in this formula should have some powers of 10 applied.

I'm using the formula:

Fc = 1 / (2π R C)

to find the capacitor value needed in-line to cut low frequencies from a pair of 6-ohm tweeters I just bought.  Their low freq is listed at 5k, but I'd like to start with a cutoff around 8k.

Wanting to cut off at 8kHz and solving for C, I use

1 / (2π * 6 * 8000) = 3.316e-06

Are there some powers of 10 to consider, like "well Ohms really means kilo-ohms, so multiply by 1k" or similar?  Similar to how 1 Calorie = 1000 calories?  Farads vs microfarads maybe?

I found a value the other day, looked for capacitors of that size, and they're the type used in safely starting air conditioners.  At least I'm a decent at soldering. :-}

Comment: You can find 3.3uF capacitors in a 0402 case - 0.04"x0.02", the size of a moderate grain of sand...they're just rated for 4V.  What voltage do you expect to see in this application?

Comment: Note that a capacitor+inductor (here the speaker voice coil) = [resonant tank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit).  Tanks are noted for their ability to produce "resonant" voltages way higher than the input voltage.  Now a speaker generally doesn't resonate (that'd sound awful) but it *may* be possible to have some certain frequency input create a higher-than-expected voltage across the capacitor.  To prevent the cap from failing due to unforeseen over-voltage, choose a voltage rating that is significantly higher than anticipated. i,.e., if 200W and 35V are expected, I'd pick a 50V one.

Comment: Thanks for all the information, this greatly helps.  @rdtsc  for my little 40-watt desktop amp connected to my computer, I figured that 16 volts would be a reasonable max limit.  So I bought Panasonic film capacitors rated at 100v, as they seemed quite adequate, and were around a buck and a half each.   But good point regarding resonant frequencies.  I hadn't thought about that increasing what I'll call the back-voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No 10X tricks here. That is a 3.3 microfarad capacitor, a common value.

Next you need to pick the type, polarized or not, & voltage rating.

For a speaker crossover you want a quality capacitor that doesn't have microphonic issues. A *film* capacitor is a good choice. These are always non-polarized (you want non-polarized).

Next calculate the voltage rating needed:

Power = Voltage squared divided by resistance.

Or, V = sqrt(P * R)

Your amp probably isn't more than 200W, so V = sqrt(200 * 6) = 35 V

Add some margin, you don't need much margin here since the power probably already has some margin.

Digikey sells quality components, that is where I buy most of my components.

[image]

Comment: Excellent explanation Mattman944!  That really clarified everything I need.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In that formula:
F = frequency in hertz
R = resistance in ohms
C = capacitance in farads

Adjust powers of 10 accordingly.

Comment: I guess I just need to get used to looking for the micro, pico, etc and knowing what powers of 10 those represent.  As Mattman mentioned, the 3.3 microfarad capacitor was cake to find.  Thanks for your help!